# How do I loop through a column's values and output corresponding rows and data in different dataframes in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

this is an elementary question I feel but I would like to make several individual data frames for text file output based on the values in a column ("broad_class") by using a loop in R.

hgnc |   broad_class | chromosome | unique id

ABC   | exc   | 1  | ...

 DEF | exc | 2 | ...

 GHI | int | 1 | ...

 JKL | int | 5 | ...

 MNO | pur | 3 | ...

 XYZ | pur | 2 | ...

this is what I have and I would like to loop through different values/variables for "broad_class" column and extract rows corresponding to "exc", "int", etc etc

```
exc_merged = merge(exc, bin_gene_dict, by.x = "hgnc", by.y = "hgnc_symbol")
exc_final = exc_merged[!duplicated(exc_merged$hgnc),] 

gene_cell_out = exc_final[c('ensembl_gene_id')]
output_path = paste0(base_dir, '/GCTA_exc_ahba_ensembl.txt')
write_delim(gene_cell_out, output_path, delim='\t', col_names = F)
```

Comment: You can do that without looping using `dplyr::group_split()` or `base::split()`.

Comment: @Limey I'm not sure how one would go about implementing that with merge() based on the variables in the column? If you would be so kind to illustrate that would be really nice!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is far from reproducible, which probably explains why you've not received any answers until now.  Problems I can see on a cursory glance are:

- You haven't explained whether your data fragment relates to `exc` or `bin_gene_dict`
- You haven't provided the other data frame
- Your data fragment is not easily converted to an input data frame
- `base_dir` is undefined

So I will use `mtcars` as a source data frame and allow you to adapt to your use case.

```
library(tidyverse)

groupedCars <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) 
# Create a list of data frames, split on the value of cyl
splitData <- groupedCars %>% group_split()

# Show one element of the list, for illustration
splitData[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 × 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
4  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
5  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
6  17.8     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
7  19.7     6  145    175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6

# Export to TSV by group.  Note the use of `file.path`, 
# which is better practice than hard coding "/" as path separator
groupedCars %>% 
  group_walk(
    function(.x, .y) {
      write_delim(
        .x, 
        file.path(".", "data", paste0("GCTA_exc_ahba_cyl", .y$cyl, ".txt")),
        delim="\t", 
        col_names=F
      )
    },
    .keep=TRUE
  )
```

Which gives the following files in the `data` folder, directly under my current working directory...

[image]